# Url rewrite in Linux Container on Azure App Service for Reactjs Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redirect, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service

I've built a sample Reactjs Application and it is deployed in a Linux container which is running on Azure App Service. My App Service url is (https://abc.azurewebsites.net) and what I require is, if any user hits with "/privacy" then it should open App Service page but address bar should have url appended with /privacy (https://abc.azurewebsites.net/privacy)

Tried with Azure Front door

My Front Door url (https://sample.azurefd.net) and added few rules to it but still I am not able to achieve my goal. So for Front Door
I need is, if any user hits Front Door url with "/privacy" then it should open App Service page but address bar should have url appended with /privacy (https://sample.azurefd.net/privacy)

If this thing work through App Service or Front Door it will work for me.

I cannot make any changes in Reactjs application because it is third party owned source code and also I am not using IIS server. So the only option is to make some changes at Azure level i.e. either App Service or Front door .

Node Server: 16.13.1 (includes npm 8.1.2)

Queries

1. If there is any alternative method to achieve this please let me know.
2. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance :-)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain">
                        <match url="/privacy" />
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://abc.azurewebsites.net" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: App service Url: www.abc.com
Another url which users want to hit : www.abc.com/privacy

Comment: Please refer [Configure the URL rewrite](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32229.azure-create-an-url-rewrite-azure-web-app.aspx)

Comment: I tried that I want /privacy appended in the url. So it didn't work for me. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Also, I tried with web.config file but it is not reading my web.config file, might be because of  node server. Web.config file can be read if it using IIS. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You can access web.config file from kudu console.

Comment: Please refer this link https://www.dvginteractive.com/configuring-optimizing-your-node-js-app-in-an-azure-app-service/

Comment: Web.config file is accessible and I can access through ftp. Here the issue is it is not reading the web.config file.

Comment: Now I have added web.config file for reference and screenshot of app service folder structure.

Comment: Is your web.config file is on wwwroot folder?

Comment: Yes Harshitha, it is wwwroot folder.

Comment: To read the web.config .. Redeploy the application and check once.

Comment: I tried deploying same code multiple time, but still it is not working.

Comment: Could you please share your web.config file.Make sure all the tags in web.config are closed properly.

Comment: I've already attached web.config under code snippet.